# ASP.NET MVC 5 function from another project within same solution always fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that contains 2 applications that are structured like this:

- App
- AppAPI

`AppAPI` references `App` and calls `AuthenticateUser` within the `ApiAccountController` class from `App`.

**AppAPI**

```
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    // This is naive endpoint for demo, it should use Basic authentication to provide token or POST request
    // GET api/token/
    public string Get(string username, string password)
    {
        if (CheckUser(username, password))
        {
            return JwtManager.GenerateToken(username);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    private bool CheckUser(string username, string password)
    {
        ApiAccountController accountController = new ApiAccountController();
        return accountController.AuthenticateUser(username,password);
    }
}
```

**App**

```
ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
PasswordHasher passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();

// GET: Account
public bool AuthenticateUser(String username, String password)
{
    try
    {
        var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
        //var user = dbContext.Users.Count(u => u.UserName == username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            log.Error(username + " not found");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, password);
            if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("Invalid password for user: " + username);
                return false;
            }
        }
        //return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error(e, "Exception found for user: " + username);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is for me to use Postman to connect to AppApi like this 
http://localhost:9000/api/token?username=user@one.com&password=P@ssw0rd
and for it to authenticate this user.

However, for some reason this has been failing by returning null even though there is already a user that has been created.

Comment: What you mean by failing ?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question. It returns null

Comment: Where did you call the `CheckUser` method? post it here please?

Comment: I updated Checkuser to show the full class

Comment: I have debugged it multiple times and it always returns null?

Comment: I think its coming from var user = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username); ? But I've tested it by calling this function from within App and it worked properly. Only when I call it from the Api app this starts to happen?

Comment: My guess is it's something to do with the way your dbContext is being created between direct invocation in app and your api one. Maybe connection string issues not being copied across or something?

Comment: My API does not have a dbContext, in my ApiAccountController I declare a dbContext beforehand and use it from there. Should I be sending a dbContext over? Basically my APIapp only takes requests and passes them to the main app

Comment: I have added how I call my dbContext

Comment: Silly question but have you checked that the code is connecting to the correct copy of the database?

Comment: Hi @ADyson, yup! I've verified it when I called this class from another class within the same application.

Comment: Another class within the API project, you mean?

Comment: Nope, another class within the App project

Comment: Well, what kind of project is "App"? Just a class library, or something else? where is your connection string? The app and the API are separate projects, they could easily have separate connection strings defined in each of their respective .config files if they have one. If you're sure the API is passing in correct values for the username, but it doesn't return the result you expected, then a common fault is simply looking in the wrong database.

Comment: Even though the App might be making the DbContext, you'll still want connection strings to be consistent between both applications as ADyson mentioned. The DbConnection will read from the config file.

Comment: App is a .Net Application and AppApi is a console application. The console application does not have a connection string because it does not directly connect to the database. It only carries requests across. What should I do?